# Generic methods with Rcpp-modules

Tags: module, rcpp

What is the appropriate place to define generic methods on classes exposed using Rcpp modules? More concretely, suppose the following source file is part of an Rcpp package. I'd like to use the + operator with the toy class 'Double':

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Double {
public:
  Double(double d);
  double get() const;
private:
  ...
};

RCPP_MODULE(my_module) {
  using namespace Rcpp;
  class_<Double>("my.double")
    .constructor<double>()
    .property("value", &Double::get);
}
```

The following R code appears to give the desired result:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  loadRcppModules()
}

.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  setMethod("+", signature(e1=my.double, e2=my.double), function(e1, e2) {
    new(my.double, e1$value + e2$value)
  }, where=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

I am, however, interested in learning the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing exactly that in the RcppBDT package.  I also find it tedious -- for many types, and many ops this gets repetitive quick -- but do not know of a better way.

Comment: Fair enough. Is it possible to patch Rcpp to provide c++ implementations for generic methods? I'm open to delivering such a fix...

Comment: Patches are always welcome, particularly if they come with documentation and unit tests. But might be best to discuss this first on rcpp-devel...

Comment: At some point, we will support operators to promote C++ operators. When this happens depends mostly on when I can get my hands on it. I'd be happy to draft a design document if someone is willing to sponsor this development. Otherwise, this will wait until I actually need it.

Comment: Is this still the only viable answer?